# jQuery extent JSON array parameter replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to understand jquery extend method ,  As per the API  [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

> The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a
>   property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be
>   completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second
>   or subsequent object. The values are not merged.

It says array or object property will not merged and will be replaced . In below example  parameter is JSON array and it is getting merged instead of getting replaced .

```
var a = {
    external : true,
    parameter : [{name:'ip1'},{name:'ip2'},{name:'ip3'}]

};
var b = {
    data:'Sumeet',
    parameter : [{name:'ip1'},{name:'ip2'}]
};


$.extend(true,a,b);

console.log(a);

Output : 


{
  data: "Sumeet",
  external: true,
  parameter: [{
     name: "ip1"
  }, {
    name: "ip2"
  }, {
    name: "ip3"
 }]
}
```

The parameter should have only ip1 and ip2

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.extend

Comment: If you had just read two more sentences :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your citation says *"by default"*. The documentation later also says:

> However, by passing `true` for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.

Full paragraph:

> The merge performed by `$.extend()` is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second or subsequent object. The values are not merged. This can be seen in the example below by examining the value of banana. However, by passing `true` for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.